# How can I print a nested error message returned from REST?

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

I am currently trying to print a nested error with Javascript, however I seem to only get the inner message as String:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/axios, data)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error.response.data.message);
});
```

> status 500 reading Api#create(String,String,Request); content:
>   {"timestamp":"2018-10-30T12:08:40.524+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"EntityStateError[message=This is my actual error that I would like to print.,code=400,service=Service,embeddedErrors=]\r\n","path":"/axios"}

I would like to only print the error after message ("This is my actual error...").

I thought I might be able to parse it as JSON, however when I use

```
console.log(JSON.parse( '"' + error.response.data.message + '"'));
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
>    in JSON at position 97 at JSON.parse ()

How could I access the actual message within the error response?

error.response.data itself:

> {timestamp: "2018-10-30T13:31:09.097+0000", status: 500, error: "Internal Server Error", message: "status 500 reading Api#create/axios"}", path: "/axios"}
>   error: "Internal Server Error"
>   message: "status 500 reading Api#create(String,String,Request); content:↵{"timestamp":"2018-10-30T13:31:09.076+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"EntityStateError[message=This is my actual error that I would like to print.,code=400,service=Cancellation,embeddedErrors=]\r\n","path":"/axios"}"
>   path: "/axios"
>   status: 500
>   timestamp: "2018-10-30T13:31:09.097+0000"

Comment: Can you share the error response data, from the console.

Comment: @TiisetsoTjabane, I have added the console log of `error.response.data` to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found a solution by splitting the String I received until only the part between message and code is left (which returns the error message I want to print).

```js
let innerError = error.response.data.message;
innerError = innerError.split('content:\n')[1];
innerError = innerError.split('message=').pop().split(',code=')[0];

console.log(innerError);
```

However, this is far from a clean solution, so I am still looking for input if anyone would be willing to give.